# To which well known group the quotient group $\mathbb R^*/\mathbb{Q}^*$ is isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

To which well known group the quotient group $\mathbb R^*/\mathbb{Q}^*$ is isomorphic, where $\mathbb R^*$ is group of non zero reals under multiplication and similarly $\mathbb Q^*$ is group of non-zero rationals under multiplication?

I know that group $\mathbb R^*/\mathbb{Q}^*$ has elements of every order as order of element like $    2^{\frac{1}{n}} \mathbb Q^* $(left coset) has order $n$. I don't know exactly which group is this. Firstly it comes in my mind the group of complex numbers of mod $1$ but unable to define isomorphism.

Please provide me isomorphic group in a simple way as I don't know group theory in very deep. Thank you.

Comment: I think this has been asked before.

Comment: It is isomorphic to the well known group $\mathbb{R}^*/\mathbb{Q}^*$

Comment: @ahulpke sir i want more simple like R; C etc.

Comment: @Shaum sir i searched it before asking.

Comment: @ahulpke as I written I though like unit modulus group of complex under multiplication.

Comment: @ahupke Q/Z is also well know but nth root of unity is more simple and both are isomorphic. I am asking like this.

Comment: There isn't a "standard" or "well-known" *other* group it is isomorphic to. It has a direct factor isomorphic to $C_2$ (given by $\pm 1$), but otherwise, it's a complicated beast. For instance, we know that a transcendence basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable and algebraically independent, which means they would generate a (multiplicative) free group of uncountable rank.  Just because other quotients have easier expressions doesn't mean *this one* does.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin sir you got my question.

Comment: Everyone did; ahulpke gave you the same answer: *this* the "well-known group" it is isomorphic to, because there isn't another one that you can point to that is "well-known" and isomorphic to it. It's just that you didn't get his answer.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin yes sir I was unable to get it. Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, isn't this group torsion-free, and, by your comment, an $\mathbb R$ vectorspace of uncountable dimension?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Right, the $\pm1$ subgroup gets moded out anyway, and $\mathbb{R}$ has not  other roots of unity. It's also divisible, so you get an uncountable divisible torsionfree group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, oop, not an $\mathbb R$ vectorspace, but $\mathbb Q$ vectorspace of uncountable dimension... I guess torsion free and uniquely-divisible is equivalent to that.

Comment: Yes; it is abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{(\mathfrak c)}$; but the isomorphism is going to be somewhat nasty.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete abelian group so it is isomorphic to a cartesian product of copies of the additive group of rational numbers and Prüfer groups.

Comment: Of course, one should add, in a non-canonical way.